# Inserting values in 2D lists in Python

Tags: python, list, insert

I'm looking for a method of inserting values to 2D lists in Python. My sample list is as follows:

```
List= [ ['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D'] ]
```

I would like to insert a value at the beginning of each list within my List, so that it would look like this:

```
List = [ ['#','A', 'B'], ['#','C', 'D'] ]
```

I have written a function as follows:

```
def Foo(l):
    rows = len(l)
    cols = len(l[0])
    for row in xrange(rows):
        l.insert(row, '#')
```

But that has given me the following output:

```
List= [ '#', '#', ['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D'] ]
```

Comment: `for row in l: row.insert(0, '#')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you do `l.insert()` it adds an item to `l` not the sub lists, to iterate over the sub lists you can do:

```
for row in l:
    row.insert(0,"#")
```

Or using `xrange`:

```
for i in xrange(len(l)):
    l[i].insert(0,"#")
```